# Autoshutdown 120 minutes after boot script

Tags: power-management

Not very familiar with linux.
Ubuntu 20.
Is there a way to setup via putty a way to execute the shutdown -h 02:00
at every boot?

I found a way on another answer but it requires a gui.

Comment: yes, add this line to your .bashrc, in your home directory

Comment: There are several ways to "make something happen" at system startup. What's your Use Case? Is it for a prank?

Comment: I setup a openvpn server in aws. Usually I start it only when I need it. If I forget to shut it down this is a failsafe to limit usage charges. I also setup a aws lambda function to shut the instance down everyday at 2 am but it’s suboptimal. No pranks :)